# iPhone - a question about @property

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am kind of newbie on Objective-C and I was looking at a code, trying to understand a few things, and I come across with this .h file:

there was a declaration like that on the @interface section

```
MyVideoClass *contrast_;
```

then below we have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyVideoClass *contrast;
@property (nonatomic, retain) FetchClass *fetchMe;
```

The strange part is that the first has an underscrore after the name and the second one, doesn't.

The other strange thing is that the guy has a call to these properties like this:

```
FetchClass *fetchOne = [self.fetchMe contrast];
```

What kind of call is that? This seems pretty insane to me. I simply cannot understand what is going on here, but the code works. pretty insane.

Can you guys explain me that? Forgive the stupid question, but I am still learning...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the top of the implementation file; you should see a line that reads

```
@synthesize contrast = contrast_;
```

The reason one would do this would be to make sure that you access properties through their setters and getters (created with `@synthesize`), rather than directly.

In that second piece of code, `self.fetchMe` grabs the `fetchMe_` property using its setter. If this guy had forgotten to use `self.` and simply written

```
FetchClass *fetchOne = [fetchMe contrast];
```

He'd get an error, since `fetchMe` doesn't exist (but `fetchMe_` does). As with all things, it's up to you whether or not to use protection.

Comment: thanks, but it is not totally clear to me. What is exactly this [self.fetchMe contrast] doing? Lets translate this to english. Setters are something that set values and getters are something that get values, right? so, what is this line doing? setting or getting value? running a method? why is the self needed?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That line is actually a mix of two objective C ways of writing things... `self.fetchMe` is accessing `fetchMe_` through the setter, and is equivalent to `[self fetchMe]`. The wrapping brackets call a method on the return value of `[self fetchMe]`... so, that code could also be written as `[[self fetchMe] contrast]`.

Comment: Also, I should note that you don't have to use that underscore notation. I actually never use it, and my synthesize lines look like `@synthesize contrast;`. Now that I look closer, the whole example is weird. Does `self.fetchMe` also have a property called `contrast`?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.... my brain was melting trying to understand that! I ready Apple docs, but as always they write in Klingon and nobody was ever able to understand what they write. Yes, there's a property called contrast on fetchMe... Thanks!

Comment: Haha, no problem! Know what you mean about the Apple Docs.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
FetchClass *fetchOne = [self.fetchMe contrast];
```

Is exactly equivalent to any of these:

```
FetchClass *fetchOne = self.fetchMe.contrast;
FetchClass *fetchOne = [[self fetchMe] contrast];
```

That is, the `.` is equivalent to a method call.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh..... thanksssssssssssssssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!